# Investment evaluation as measure of forecast success

Tags: forecasting, arima, finance

I have created some R markdown to see whether certain forecasts perform better when used as information for a trading/investmen strategy.

One surprising fact I found, if an **uncorrelated** series with similar structure is used as the forecast, then returns seem to be positive and higher than forecasts based on the actual series.

Has this been studied? Is this a known phenomenon?

I only test this on simulated data and 1 stock, obviously with many real series it could change.

https://dirknbr.github.io/forecast.R/R/invest_eval/invest_eval.html

If you find any bugs, do let me know.

Comment: I think you should try to make the post self contained so that the main material would not be outsourced.

Comment: With all due respect, financial time series may be random walks but that does not mean uncorrelated. You really need to test this out on real data to be able to draw any conclusions. My best guess is that real world financial data will disconfirm it.